# What is κ(G) and κ′(G) and δ(G) for graph G?

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation, graph-connectivity

[image: G]

Am I correct to say that G is 4-connected?

So κ(G) = 4 but then κ′(G)=2 but that cannot happen since κ(G)<=κ′(G)<=δ(G)

I know δ(G)=4 so wouldn't κ′(G)=4 then? However, I don't see how that would happen.

Could someone please explain this?

Comment: What makes you think $\kappa'(G)=2$?

Comment: Sorry, I corrected it. I meant κ(G) =4. I'm thinking that the 4 middle vertices that are on the horizontal axis are the set of cut vertices, and if those are removed the graph disconnects into 2 parts making κ′(G)=2

Comment: The edge-connectivity of G, written κ′(G) is the minimum size of a disconnecting set. <- definition from my professor.

Comment: You mean "a disconnecting set" of **edges**, right? Do you see a way to disconnect your graph by removing $2$ (or $3$ edges? I don't.

Comment: neither do I, which is why I said 4. And the definition stops after disconnecting set.

Comment: If you don't see a way to disconnect the graph by removing two edges, then it is a mystery to me why you say that $\kappa'(G)=2.$

Answer (score 3):

I hope it can help you
**[Vertex Connectivity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VertexConnectivity.html):** $\kappa(G)$ is the minimum size of a vertex set S s.t. G\S is disconnected.
 **[Edge Connectivity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EdgeConnectivity.html):** $\lambda(G) $ or  $\kappa'(G)$ is the minimum size of edge set F s.t. G\F has more than one component.

[image]

in your graph $\kappa(G)=4$: for example $S=\{f,l,i,c\}$ and
 $\lambda(G)=4 $  for example $F=\{\{f,e\},\{l,k\},\{i,g\},\{c,d\}\}$

$\kappa(G)\le\lambda(G)\le\delta(G)$
(Whitney 1932, Harary 1994):
for your graph $\kappa(G)=\lambda(G)=\delta(G)=4$